# How to define inQTree

Tags: haskell

I'm currently doing a project where one of the objectives is to define the in and out of a QTree.
The datatype QTree is defined as

```
data QTree a=Cell a Int Int | Block (Qtree a) (Qtree a) (Qtree a) (Qtree a)
```

I was able to define outQTree however with inQTree I've had no such luck.

```
inQTree :: Either (a, (Int, Int)) (QTree a, (QTree a, (QTree a, QTree a))) -> QTree a
```

Predefined inQTree type.

The answer as far as I'm aware should look something like:

```
 inQTree=either Cell Block
```

But Haskell naturally complains that both Cell and Block are not being applied to enough arguments.
Any ideas on how to get it working?

Comment: Can you explain why you think the answer should be `either Cell Block`, and why you think this has to be the signature, instead of `Eq a => a -> QTree a -> Bool`?

Comment: In a earlier question it was necessary to also define the in and out of another type, which was Blockchain=Bc{bc::Block}|Bcs{bcs::(Block,Blockchain)}  and in this one the inBlockChain=either Bc Bcs

Comment: Well this *strange* as well, you seem to define some sort of "constructor".

Comment: >> But Haskell naturally complains that both Cell and Block are not being applied to enough arguments. << Sure, because `either :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Either a b -> c`, and if you want `Cell` to be the first argument of `either` to produce your current `inQTree` type, `Cell` should be of type `(a, (Int, Int)) -> QTree a`, but `Cell` is actually `a -> Int -> Int -> QTree a`.

Comment: @SnowOnion for the purposes of this exercise we are not allowed to change any predefined types, so sadly Cell must remain `a->Int->Int->QTree a`

Comment: I think i figured it out by defining 2 more functions  `inBlock (a,(b,(c,d)))=Block a b c d
inCell (a,(b,c))=Cell a b c` and `inQTree= either inCell inBlock`

Comment: @wvstealth Ok. Just curious: Are you forced to use `either` in the answer? Otherwise you may pattern-match `Left` and `Right` cases respectively.

Comment: @SnowOnion About 80% sure, at least as far as the inQTree is concerned, outQTree i had to use left and right for the answer.